# Pasar variable de jsp a un web service

Tags: java, webservice, jsp

tengo el siguiente problema:
Resulta que debo desplegar datos en una tabla, que provienen de un web service,
pero lo que necesito es obtener el id de ese dato y enviarlo a otro web service para obtener los datos de ese en especifico.

Para ello cree la variable "seleccion" con jsp fuera de la tabla:

```
        <%
          int seleccion = 0;
        %>
```

Luego tengo la tabla de la siguiente forma, llenada con los datos que llamo del web service:

```
        <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Equipo</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <%
                    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                %> 
                <tr>

                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getIdInspeccion()); %></th>
                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getNombreEquipo()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getFecha()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getHora()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getDireccion()); %></td>
                    <td><% out.println(lista.get(i).getEstadoInspeccion()); %></td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="<% out.println(lista.get(i).getIdInspeccion()); %>" id="insid">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="" onclick="" >Actualizar</button>
                        <button onclick="alert(<% out.println(seleccion); %>);">prueba</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Como pueden ver al presional el boton opciones, se despliega un modal, el cual lo saque de bootstrap, entonces intento asignarle en ese lugar, el id de ese dato a la variable que cree anteriormente.

Luego con eso llamaria al web service:

```
    <%
        //ACA SE DEFINEN LAS VARIABLES PARA CARGAR LOS DATOS DE LA INSPECCION EN EL MODAL
        int idIns = 0;              //id
        String estIns = "";         //estado
        String resIns = "";         //resultado
    %>           


    <%-- start web service invocation --%>
    <%

        try {
            clienteWeb.ServicioGestionInspeccion_Service service = new clienteWeb.ServicioGestionInspeccion_Service();
            clienteWeb.ServicioGestionInspeccion port = service.getServicioGestionInspeccionPort();
            // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
            int idInspeccion = 0;
            // TODO process result here

            clienteWeb.Inspeccion result = port.obtenerResultado(seleccion);
            //out.println("Result = " + result);
            idIns = result.getIdInspeccion();
            estIns = result.getEstadoInspeccion();
            resIns = result.getResultado();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO handle custom exceptions here
        }
    %>
    <%-- end web service invocation --%>
```

En la parte donde le intento pasar el valor de la variable seleccion siempre me sale que es nulo:

clienteWeb.Inspeccion result = port.obtenerResultado(seleccion);

Como podria pasar el valor del id del dato de la tabla al web service?? 
muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estás bastante confundido sobre como funcionan los JSPs:

1. El navegador llama al servidor.
2. En el servidor se ejecuta el JSP. Ese es el código en los *scriptlets* (entre `<% ... %>` o `<%!...%>`).
3. La ejecución del JSP genera una página web (HTML, HTML + JS) que devuelve al navegador. Ahí es donde está el *select*.
4. El navegador muestra la página web. **La ejecución del JSP ya ha terminado, y además el JSP se ejecuta en otra máquina**. No puedes "combinar" el JSP con usar el HTML que genera éste. Cuando puedes actuar con el *select* ya no existe la variable *seleccion* del JSP.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar Ajax para **hacer una nueva petición desde el servidor al navegador** y ejecutar un WS que te devuelva los datos que buscas.